# I need to check each row contains a Specified value or not

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Six Columns Containing more than 5K records. I want Check each of the six columns for 5K records whether the specified value is present or not. If present it has to be added in a new column with respect to the corresponding row

I have tried for a single column as `ad6` but I have to check for `ad5`, `ad4`,`ad3` if `ad6` contains the value, it's value will be got or else go for `ad5` if it has value it has to  get, or else `ad4` and so on...

```
SELECT ad6,

CASE WHEN ad6 = 'NW' or ad6 = 'SW' or ad6 = 'SE'or ad6= 'NE' or ad6 = 'N' or ad6 = 'S' or ad6 = 'E' or ad6 ='W'or ad6 ='C'
THEN (ad6) 
ELSE null
END as sector

FROM public."Add_disp";
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you share some sample data and the results you'd want to get for it?

Comment: select ad6,ad5,ad4,ad3,ad2,ad1,
 case when ad6 = 'NW' or ad6 = 'SW' or ad6 = 'SE'or ad6= 'NE' or ad6 = 'N' or ad6 = 'S' or ad6 = 'E' or ad6 ='W'or ad6 ='C' then ad6
when  ad5 = 'NW' or ad5 = 'SW' or ad5 = 'SE'or ad5= 'NE' or ad5 = 'N' or ad5 = 'S' or ad5 = 'E' or ad5 ='W'or ad5 ='C' then ad5 
when  ad4 = 'NW' or ad4 = 'SW' or ad4 = 'SE'or ad4= 'NE' or ad4 = 'N' or ad4 = 'S' or ad4 = 'E' or ad4 ='W'or ad4 ='C' then ad4

 else null ; end as quadrant; from public."Add_disp"

Comment: I have done the above code with reference to @Khillare(below answer) but in that I got the answer as a temperory column, I want it to be real column in a table, and like this code (quadrant) I have some other code for (st_name,house_no) can I be able to Integrate all into a Single code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to continue using additional cases like you did for `ad6`. I haven't tested the syntax below but this should help you build the query.

```
merge into some_table t
using (
    select some_row_id,
           case when ad6 = 'some value' then ad6
                when ad5 = 'some value' then ad5
                when ad4 = 'some value' then ad4
                when ad3 = 'some value' then ad3
                when ad2 = 'some value' then ad2
                when ad1 = 'some value' then ad1
                else null 
           end as sector
      from some_table where 1=1) AS v
ON t.some_row_id = v.some_row_id
WHEN MATCHED
    update SET t.some_col = v.sector
```

Comment: Does Postgres support `merge`?  I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: I can't able to run the Code but the body of this code is slightly Changed and make it work for me , with some manual process